# How can I implement random access iterators for my container?

Tags: c++, iterator

This is the header file for the container including a try to implement random access iterators :

```
using namespace std;
template <class Element, class Compare = std::equal_to<Element>>
class UniqueArray {

public:
    Element** data;
    unsigned int curr_size;
    unsigned int max_size;
    int* availability_array;

    explicit UniqueArray(unsigned int size);
    UniqueArray(const UniqueArray& other);
    ~UniqueArray();
//    UniqueArray& operator=(const UniqueArray&) = delete;
    unsigned int insert(const Element& element);
    bool getIndex(const Element& element, unsigned int& index) const;
    const Element* operator[] (const Element& element) const;
    bool remove(const Element& element);
    unsigned int getCount() const;
    unsigned int getSize() const;

    class Filter {
    public:
        virtual bool operator() (const Element&) const = 0;
    };
    UniqueArray filter(const Filter& f) const;

    class UniqueArrayIsFullException{};

    typedef Element ua_iterator;
    typedef const Element ua_const_iterator;

    ua_iterator begin(){
        return **data;
    }
    ua_const_iterator begin() const {
        return **data;
    }
    ua_iterator end(){
        return *(*data + max_size);
    }
    ua_const_iterator end() const {
        return *(*data + max_size);
    }
};
```

A summary of the errors I get :

`error: no match for ‘operator++’`

`error: no match for ‘operator*’`

`error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<MtmParkingLot::Vehicle>`

`error: no match for ‘operator!=’`

`error: no match for ‘operator-’`

On my implementation `Element` gets `Vehicle` and all these missing operators refer to `Vehicle`

I'm not quite sure on how to work on these errors because for example substracting `Vehicles` makes no sense..

Comment: Its an array of pointers to ```Element``` objects. 
I can't assume that the ```Element``` provided has a default constructor

Comment: You can't use the elements themselves as iterators. You need to iterate over your array.

Comment: I want to iterate over elements @Evg

Comment: You are not supposed to substract or add vehicles. You are supposed to add or substract to the ADRESS of a vehicle instance in order to get the last/next vehicles adress. You need to understand, that an iterator is a pointer to a vehicle instance and not the instance itself.

Comment: @Max meaning i need to change these lines : 

`typedef Element ua_iterator;
    typedef const Element ua_const_iterator;`

to : 
  `typedef Element* ua_iterator;
    typedef const Element* ua_const_iterator;`

Comment: Rather than `Element** data; unsigned int curr_size; unsigned int max_size; int* availability_array;`, why not `std::vector<Element> data;`?

Comment: @Caleth not allowed to use STL on this class(besides `std::equal_to`) .. Uni hw requirements

Comment: Do you have an existing `Homework::Vector` template?

Comment: No

(writing stuff so i can hit ` add comment`)

Comment: Could you please describe what type of container your `UniqueArray` is supposed to be and why an `Element **` data member is needed?

Comment: @Bob__ I can't assume that Element has a default constructor so I dont have a way to initialize an array without knowing its objects content (can't use STL besides `equal_to`)
So I implemented this as an array of pointers to `Element` objects which is initialized at the begginig to `nullptr` and later when an `Element` is about to enter the array I call the copy-constructor (which I can assume I have)

Answer (score 3):

If you want an iterator to return a reference to an object when it is dereferenced, you have to define a special `Iterator` class to do it. With [`boost::indirect_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html) this is pretty simple:

```
#include <boost/iterator/indirect_iterator.hpp>

template <class Element, class Compare = std::equal_to<Element>>
class UniqueArray {
    // ...

    auto begin() {
        return boost::indirect_iterator<Element**, Element>(data_);
    }

    auto end() {
        return boost::indirect_iterator<Element**, Element>(data_ + curr_size);
    }
};
```

[Simple demo](https://godbolt.org/z/i_f-sE)

---

If you want to code it yourself, the idea is:

```
template<class Element>
class UniqueArray {
public:
    //...

    class Iterator {
    public:
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = Element;
        using reference = Element&;
        // ...

        Iterator(Element** d) : data(d) { }

        reference operator*() {
            return **data;
        }

        Iterator& operator++() {
            ++data;
            return *this;
        } 

        friend bool operator!=(Iterator it1, Iterator it2) {
            return it1.data != it2.data;
        }

        // ...

    private:
        Element** data;        
    };

    Iterator begin() {
        return Iterator(data);
    }

    Iterator end() {
        return Iterator(data + curr_size);
    }
};
```

Note, the [full random access iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) requires implementation of many other member and non-member functions. You might want to make it a [forward iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) to simplify things a little bit.

[Simple demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qvhAKs)

Comment: @EliranTurgeman, you should install [Boost](https://www.boost.org/) first, it is not a standard library.

Comment: Since i need it to compile on a remote linux server, compiling it on my machine with libraries that the server don't have won't help. 
I need to use only the standard library

Comment: @EliranTurgeman, Boost.Iterator should be a header-only library, you don't need to compile Boost.

Comment: Ok, but the server will generate the same error I have now `file not found`.
I will dive into your second solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you write that without the type aliases, you get definitions like

```
Element begin(){
    return **data;
}
```

and use like

```
UniqueArray<Vehicle>::ua_iterator it = something.begin();
it++;
```

becomes

```
Vehicle it = something.begin();
it++;
```

which makes the cause of the errors more obvious - you're trying to apply iterator operations to your element type.

If you're fine with iteration producing `Element*`, the simple solution is

```
typedef Element** ua_iterator;

ua_iterator begin(){
    return data;
}
ua_iterator end(){
    return data + curr_size;
}
```

and similar for the const versions.

Then you could write

```
UniqueArray<Vehicle>::ua_iterator it = something.begin();
Vehicle* v = *it;
```

If you want iteration to produce `Element&`, you need to write an iterator class with the appropriate overloads and traits.
It's not very difficult, but it gets tedious.